# Converting nested JSON to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

"I have a JSON file that contains  multiple entries like:

```
{
    "id": "01",
    "alpha_values": [
        {
            "val1": "1234",
            "val2": "5678",
            "bravo_values": [
                {
                    "val3": "ab_987",
                    "val4": "wd_123",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm reading the file into a pandas dataframe which is successful

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize


file = "my.json"
with open(file) as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
df = json_normalize(data)
print(df)
```

However, the result looks like two columns only when I really need each value to be in its own column.

*current results*

```
id                            alpha_values
1  [{'val1': '1234', 'val2': '5678', bravo_values[{'val3':'ab_987', 'val4': 'wd_123'}]}]
```

*desired results*

```
id     val1     val2      val3     val4 
1     '1234'   '5678'   'ab_987'  'wd_123'
```

Suggestions?

Comment: I am mostly sure you will need to create a custom procedure to load this json.

Answer (score 0):

it should work:

Here `data` is your nested json data.

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Flatten the json first:

```
def reshape(blob, final={}):
    for k,v in blob.items():
        if not isinstance(v, list):
            final.update({k: v})
        else:
            for item in v:
                reshape(item, final)

    return final

c = reshape(d)

df = pd.DataFrame([c])

   id  val1  val2    val3    val4
0  01  1234  5678  ab_987  wd_123
```